# Button click event integration

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am currently making searching platform for materials, and I want to make a button with periodic table. what I am doing now is to make every button for the periodic table, and making every click events for each button.

```
public void bc(string a)
{
    if (MainEntry.Text == "")
    {
        MainEntry.Text = a;
    }
    else
    {
        MainEntry.Text = MainEntry.Text + "," + a;
    }
}
private void buttonLi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bc("Li");
}
private void buttonBe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bc("Be");
}
```

I wonder if there are another option for this. such as, if I press the button, system reads what is written on the button, and use the text on the method. So that I can decrease my code lines.

Comment: Are you using winform ?

Comment: Start from *extracing model* (data): let have a *single collection* of elements. Do not *hardcode* `bc("Li");`

Comment: You can use the *same* method as an event handler. `sender` is the button itself so you can modify your code based on that. Eg, you can use the `Text` to decide what to send based on the button's text, or the `Tag` property. All controls have a `Tag` property that's used to store extra info

Comment: The best option is Tag - it's available everywhere, doesn't force you to use a specific Text and far more important, doesn't break localization

Comment: @Cid Yes, I am using windows form :)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you :) you also helped me to understand this further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply call the same `onclick` method for every button and get the text within the `Onclick` Event. Something like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;

    bc(button.Text);
}
```

Comment: If, for some reasons, the method is used on something else than a Button, You'll get a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: `Text` is a property of Control

Comment: Thank you for your help! your answer helped me and saved my time alot!

Comment: @JaehoSong not yet - using `Text` prevents you from localizing the form. If you do, you'll have to look up the localized label each time to find out which button was used. Use `Tag` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Sender` object, but first you need to subscribe all button clicks to the one event, something like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    buttonLi.Click += button_Click;
    buttonBe.Click += button_Click;
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    bc(btn.Text);
}
```

The Sender contains a reference to the control/object that raised the event.

Comment: But first you need to listen to`Click` event all buttons in designer.
You can do this with two way, first; with UI Designer select to Button and go to Events tab in Properties, found the `Click` event and select Event or on form load you can write code something like;
buttonLi.Click += Element_Click;
buttonBe.Click += Element_Click;

Comment: @UmutÇömlekçioğlu you can pick or specify an available event handler in the designer, or explicitly add the handler. In both cases the same code is emmitted

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You both really helped me I really do appreciate it

Comment: @SalahAkbari Thank you :) But I chose other person's coding since I didn't need initialization and I thought it does fit on my case more. But really thank you for teaching new-bie

Comment: @JaehoSong I didn't intent to show you how can you use initialization, I just was trying to show that all of your buttons need to listen to the same event handler in order you can use the sender object in it's right order. Exactly like what Umut said in his comment but this is the code alternative for his suggestion. :)

Comment: @SalahAkbari I understood :) I didn't know I would be able to get this nice answers from everyone. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `Tag` property of a control.

Something like:

```
private void control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Control)sender;

    bc(control.Tag.ToString());
}
```

This way you don't have to create an eventhandler for each button. And using the Tag will offer that the `Text` that is shown on the button don't have to be equal.

---

Use `(Control)sender` over `sender as Control`, because if something is wrong you don't want the exception "NullReferenceException" but the real exception what went wrong. *(Like invalid casts exceptions)*

---

*Select the button on the form*

[image: Form1 with button]

*Fill the tag with the right value*

[image: Tag property]

Comment: `Tag` is a property of `Control`. By casting to `Control` you can use this code with every control

Comment: A huge benefit of `Tag` vs `Text` is that `Text` will change when the form is localized. `Tag` doesn't affect how the button or the rest of the form works though

Comment: Yep, thats what I had in mind also. I never use Text/Captions values back in code, because of Culture stuff. If someone changes a caption, the application will break otherwise.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Thank you for your kind comment, I got an error message from it, (**System.Windows.Forms.Control.Tag.get returned null.**) but I will figure it out myself :) Thank you for your time

Comment: @JaehoSong you need to set the `Tag` first.. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Thank you for kind answer :) I am sorry for my stupidness but please understand me that I am very beginner. Again, thank you for your time :) Everyone of you are awesome!